# Transforming Windows 7 into Windows 98/Me

Tags: windows-7

I would like to know if there's any theme/transformation pack for Windows 7 that allows Windows 7 to look  like Windows 98/Me.

If not, is there access to content such as cursors, sounds, wallpapers, etc?

Comment: -1 This is a simple question covered within Windows 7 and even more extensively on the Microsoft site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows%2098%20theme%20for%20windows%207&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=sy6&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&source=hp&q=make%20windows%207%20look%20like%2098&pbx=1&oq=make%20windows%207%20look%20like%2098&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=37535l43990l0l44553l33l14l4l12l13l1l357l3399l0.3.9.2l29l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=b53e645ed3c6a495&biw=1600&bih=1096) pointed me to many articles.

Take a look at [this page](http://windows7.techkicker.com/2011/08/27/how-to-make-windows-7-look-like-9598nt2000me/) giving a video on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i made some searches but probably was using wrong keyword.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an explanation also, giving your answer a little more content?